# How do I know whether I'm looking at a newline or carriage return etc.?

Tags: parsing, newline, carriage-return

For example, say I wanted to determine whether this form was storing newlines as carriage returns or newlines or whatever characters.  I'm often in situations where I'm writing code and am not sure what type of new-line character a file/form/whatever I'm parsing is using.

How could I determine this?  Is there a way to determine this without actually doing a check inside of code?  (It seems like I should be able to right-click and "show all characters" or something like that).

Note: I realize I could write code saying

```
(if == '\r') cout << "Carriage";
```

etc
but I have a feeling there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is list what you are looking for (from vim help):

```
:[range]l[ist] [count] [flags]
                        Same as :print, but display unprintable characters
                        with '^' and put $ after the line.  This can be
                        changed with the 'listchars' option.
                        See ex-flags for [flags].
```

You can switch modes with:

```
:set list
```

and

```
:set nolist
```

Additionally you can use "listchars" as shown in this [example](https://superuser.com/questions/97692/vim-show-line-feeds-carriage-return):

Answer (score 0):

You could for example check your document for occourences of "Carriage Return"  or "New Line"/"Line Feed".

e.g. (php):

```
if(  strstr( $yourstring , "\r" ) != false  ){ // You have Carriage return
  // Do something
}
elseif(  strstr( $yourstring , "\n" ) != false  ){ // You have New Line/Line feed
  // Do something
}
else{
  // You cannot determine which on is used, because the string is single-lined
}
```

I hope this is the thing you're looking for

Note: In windows "\r\n" is used to specify ne lines